# PHP does not display on HTML page

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to make a dropdown list of genres that a user can select and then view all the series in that genre. Here is my HTML code

```
<td><p>Select a Genre to View</p>

<form id=”form1” method=”post” action=”view_process.php”>
</br>
<?php include("dropdown.php"); ?>

</br>
<input style="display:none" type="submit" id="sub"/>
</form>
```

And then here is my PHP for the drop down:

```
<?php
require_once 'login_sec217.php'; 
$db_server = mysqli_connect($db_hostname, $db_username, $db_password, 
$db_database);
if (!$db_server) die("Unable to connect to MySQL: " . 
mysqli_error($db_server));

$query = "SELECT genre_name FROM genres;";
$results = mysqli_query($db_server, $query);
if(!$results)
die("Query Error: "  . mysqli_error($db_server));
else {
echo "<select id=\"opt\" name=\"name\"onchange=\"showButton()\">";
echo "<option value=\"none\">please select</option>";
while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($results))
{
foreach($row as $key=>$value) ${$key}=$value;
echo "<option value=\"&genre_name\">$genre_name</option>";
}
echo "</select>";
}
?>
```

and for my table of the results:

```
<?php
foreach($_POST as $key=>$value) ${key}=$value;
require_once 'login_sec217.php'; 
$db_server = mysqli_connect($db_hostname, $db_username, $db_password, 
$db_database);
if (!$db_server) die("Unable to connect to MySQL: " . 
mysqli_error($db_server));
$query = "SELECT s.series_title, s.series_author_last, s.series_author_first 
FROM series s INNER JOIN 
genrelink.l ON s.series_id = l.series_id INNER JOIN genres g ON g.genre_id = 
l.genre_id WHERE g.genre_name 
= '$name';";
$result = mysqli_query($db_server,$query);
?>
<table width="100%">
<tr>
<th>Title</th>
<th>Author Last Name</th>
<th>Author First Name</th>
</tr>
<tr>
<?php
$row = mysqli_fetch_row($result);
echo "<td>$row[0]</td>";
echo "<td>$row[1]</td>";
echo "<td>$row[2]</td>";
?>
</tr>
</table>
```

The PHP seems to operate perfectly standing alone, but when I put them on the webpage...nothing appears. The database is connecting but something with the insertion into the HTML page is screwing with this? Any thoughts would be awesome.

Comment: Please note that the `mysql_*` functions have been **deprecated since 2013** (in PHP 5.5), and are **removed as of PHP 7** (released in 2015). This is because they have **serious** security vulnerabilities. **DO NOT USE THEM**. Please consider upgrading your PHP and switching to either [**MySQLi**](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [**PDO**](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) instead, ensuring that you also use [**prepared statements**](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) to prevent [**SQL injection**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection).

Comment: Also, you have no variable `$audience` defined. You're looking for `$_POST['audience']`, though you should **NEVER** use user input (like `$_POST`) directly in SQL statements! You should use [**prepared statements**](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) instead, binding your `$_POST` variables to parameters.

Comment: Sorry, I accidentally posted a question I already fixed. I definitely redid that page with mysqli!

Answer (score -2):

change your code like this

```
<tr><td><input type="checkbox" name="genre[]" value="1" />Action </td>
<td><input type="checkbox" name="genre[]" value="2" />Adventure </td></tr>
<tr><td><input type="checkbox" name="genre[]" value="3" />Comedy</td>
<td><input type="checkbox" name="genre[]" value="4" />Coming of Age</td></tr>
<tr><td><input type="checkbox" name="genre[]" value="5" />Dark fantasy</td>
<td><input type="checkbox" name="genre[]" value="6" />Drama</td></tr>
<tr><td><input type="checkbox" name="genre[]" value="7" />Fantasy</td>
```

Comment: Thank you! I saw something similar to that another forum, not sure if it applied to my case.

Comment: debug using ````var_dump($_POST); exit();```` in your php file see whether audience value is comming or not.

Comment: Sorry, actually was curious about why this was so off topic and realized I accidentally posted a question about code I already fixed. Above is the new, updated question. I eliminated the old code and re-did it with mysqli